# Windows filesystem API different outputs

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, filesystems

At my workplace, we have an interface wrapped over Win32 filesystem API's which allows us to do bunch of file ops. In that we have one operation which essentially calls `GetFileAttributesExW` followed by `FindFirstFileExW`.

Here is a simple standalone use case for it.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <errno.h>
#include <memory>

struct file_handle_close
{
    void operator()(void *handle) const
    {
        if (static_cast<HANDLE>(handle) != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        {
            CloseHandle(static_cast<HANDLE>(handle));
        }
    }
};

typedef std::unique_ptr<void, file_handle_close>  file_handle_uptr;

void function2(const std::wstring& path)
{
    WIN32_FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DATA attr_ctx;

    if (GetFileAttributesExW(path.c_str(), GetFileExInfoStandard, &attr_ctx) == 0)
    {    
        DWORD  error_code(GetLastError());
        std::cout << "Error occurred in GetFileAttributesExW : "<< error_code << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {     
        std::cout << "This is all good in GetFileAttributesExW!!!\n\n" ;
    }

}

void function3(const std::wstring& path)
{
    file_handle_uptr                         handle_uptr;
    WIN32_FIND_DATAW                     file_attr;
    DWORD                                error_code = ERROR_SUCCESS;

    handle_uptr.reset(FindFirstFileExW(path.c_str(), FindExInfoBasic, &file_attr, FindExSearchNameMatch, nullptr, 0));

    if (static_cast<HANDLE>(handle_uptr.get()) == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        DWORD  error_code(GetLastError());
        std::cout << "Error occurred in FindFirstFileExW : "<< error_code << std::endl; 
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "This is all good in FindFirstFileExW!!!\n\n" ;
    }
}

int main(int argc,char** argv)
{
    if(argc < 2)
    {
        std::cout << "Please enter a path!!!"<<std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        const std::string str = argv[1];
        const std::wstring wstr(str.begin(),str.end());

        function2(wstr);
        function3(wstr);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I have two paths with mixed permissions.

```
C:\TEMP\Dir1\Dir2 : Dir1 has permissions denied for current user
C:\TEMP\DIRX\DIRY\DIRZ : DIRX and DIRY have permissions denied for current user
```

I denied the permissions using following command

```
%icacls directoryname /deny username:(RX)
```

I use these paths as an input to .exe file created by above code. I get following output.

```
B:\testfun>.\testfun.exe C:\TEMP

This is all good in GetFileAttributesExW!!!

This is all good in FindFirstFileExW!!!


B:\testfun>.\testfun.exe C:\TEMP\Dir1

This is all good in GetFileAttributesExW!!!

This is all good in FindFirstFileExW!!!


B:\testfun>.\testfun.exe C:\TEMP\Dir1\Dir2  <-------- This

This is all good in GetFileAttributesExW!!!

Error occurred in FindFirstFileExW : 5


B:\testfun>.\testfun.exe C:\TEMP\DIRX

This is all good in GetFileAttributesExW!!!

This is all good in FindFirstFileExW!!!


B:\testfun>.\testfun.exe C:\TEMP\DIRX\DIRY
Error occurred in GetFileAttributesExW : 5
Error occurred in FindFirstFileExW : 5


B:\testfun>.\testfun.exe C:\TEMP\DIRX\DIRY\DIRZ   <-------- This

This is all good in GetFileAttributesExW!!!

Error occurred in FindFirstFileExW : 5
```

What I want to understand is the difference in the behavior of these functions.

Why is `GetFileAttributesExW` gives different output as opposed to `FindFirstFileExW` which seems to honor the permissions set on the directories ?

I am using Windows 10 Build 16299 with VS 2017 compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all let look how [`FindFirstFileExW`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364419(v=vs.85).aspx) use first parameter `lpFileName` - this is not final and exactly path to file which used to open. api is **parse and split** this string. it search for last trailing backslash **`\`** in this string and split it to 2 strings. then it the first part of `lpFileName` (before last trailing backslash) if used as path to folder which system is try open with `FILE_READ_DATA | SYNCHRONIZE`  access. and second part of `lpFileName` used (after wrap to `UNICODE_STRING`) in call [`NtQueryDirectoryFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/ntifs/nf-ntifs-ntquerydirectoryfile) in place `FileName` parameter - *An optional pointer to a caller-allocated Unicode string containing the name of a file (or multiple files, if wildcards are used) within the directory specified by FileHandle.*

for example if you call `FindFirstFileExW(L"C:\\TEMP\\Dir1\\Dir2", ..)` the `C:\TEMP\Dir1\Dir2` split to `C:\TEMP\Dir1` and `Dir2`. and system try open `C:\TEMP\Dir1` (and got here access denied) and then (if open ok) will be search `Dir2` (exactly) file in folder - not big sense at all - usually we use wildcard characters, for example, an `C:\TEMP\Dir1\*`.

in opposite [`GetFileAttributesEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364946(v=vs.85).aspx) used `lpFileName` as exactly name of the file .

so when you call

```
FindFirstFileExW(L"C:\\TEMP\\Dir1\\Dir2", ..);
GetFileAttributesEx(L"C:\\TEMP\\Dir1\\Dir2", ..);
```

you test 2 **different** folders:

`C:\TEMP\Dir1` (for 1 line) and `C:\TEMP\Dir1\Dir2` (for second line) - It is not surprising that the results of access may be different. at second - this api use **different** access to folders - `FindFirstFileExW` require `FILE_READ_DATA` when `GetFileAttributesEx` require `FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES` access only. so by this also can be different results. also note that `FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES` is special access for file systems. the ntfs (for example ) grant `FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES` access to caller in 2 case - of if caller direct have `FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES` access on file, or if caller have `FILE_LIST_DIRECTORY` access for **parent** folder (as side note - same situation with `DELETE` access - we can got it if explicit have for file or (if not) if we have `FILE_DELETE_CHILD` access on parent folder).

if case calls to `C:\TEMP\Dir1` - `GetFileAttributesEx` not fail, because you have access `FILE_LIST_DIRECTORY`  on parent `C:\TEMP` folder.
`FindFirstFileExW` not fail because it really open `C:\TEMP` to which you have `FILE_READ_DATA` access (also note that `FILE_READ_DATA == FILE_LIST_DIRECTORY == 1` )

---

`C:\TEMP\DIRX`

`GetFileAttributesExW`and `FindFirstFileExW` ok because user have `FILE_READ_DATA` (same as `FILE_LIST_DIRECTORY`) on `C:\TEMP`

`C:\TEMP\DIRX\DIRY`

`GetFileAttributesExW` fail because user have not `FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES` on `DirY` and have not `FILE_LIST_DIRECTORY` on `DirX`. `FindFirstFileExW` fail because user have not `FILE_READ_DATA` on `DirX`

`C:\TEMP\DIRX\DIRY\DIRZ`

`GetFileAttributesExW` ok - user have `FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES` access for `DirZ`. `FindFirstFileExW` fail because user have not `FILE_READ_DATA` on `DirY`